# Rails 4 Search By Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, search-form

I want to put a search form on my homepage at pages#home. I'd like to be able to search my model by category. I haven't been able to find a solution where you're actually putting the logic on a different controller than the models you're searching on. I was wondering if someone could help with the syntax and where it needs to go. Here are my relations:

**vendor.rb**

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :category_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :vendor
end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
def home
  @vendors = Vendor.all
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
root 'pages#home'
```

I'm trying to put the search form on home.html.erb, which is under the pages layouts. Was hoping someone could help with how I can accomplish this. This being (seemingly) a simple type of search, I'd hopefully not have to use a gem.

**EDIT: ANSWER**
For those searching, here's what worked. Thank you @Vla

**vendors_controller.rb**

```
def search
  @vendors = Vendor.search(params)
end
```

**pages/home.html.erb** (this is my root 'pages#home')

```
<%= form_tag vendors_search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Vendors" %>
  <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(Category.all.map{|el| [el.name, el.id]}) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb** (make sure to put this near the top)

```
get 'vendors/search'
```

**vendors/search.html.erb**

```
<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <%= vendor.name %>
  <%= vendor.phone %>
  <%= vendor.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What page will render the results?

Comment: I'd personally `root 'vendors#index'`, and send search params to index, or `search` action, then re-render `index`. If your `pages#home` action contained anything other than `@vendors`, I might consider another approach, but so far it looks like a `vendors#index` action. How are your views structured? `pages/home` renders `vendors` partial? Separate the responsibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, You can do it this way:

Go to Your vendor.rb file and add search method like this:

```
def self.search params    
  vendors = Vendor.where(category_id: params[:category].to_i) unless params[:category].blank?
  vendors
end
```

Then in Your vendors_controller create search method:

```
def search
  @vendors = Vendor.search(params)
end
```

Then create form at homepage similar to:

```
= form_tag search_vendors_path, method: :get, role: 'form' do
  .form-group
    %label Category
    = select_tag 'category', options_for_select(Category.all.map{|el| [el.name, el.id]}), class: 'form-control'
    = submit_tag 'Search'
```

And do not forget to put

```
get  'vendors/search'
```

into Your routes and add "search" view.

You can still do the same without search action, with result on Your homepage. Anyway I hope You got the idea.